# readfile equivalent for binary data?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm using http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation to access private files using php. I can get the data of the file by saying $object->body. I actually want to see the image in the browser or play the video in a video player. Is there a way to do that?

I think I need something like readfile. The problem is readfile is I need the path to the file. The path is private so I cannot use that. Is there a way to do a readfile of the binary data?

I put this in the php thinking this would help but it still displays the binary data.

```
header('Content: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=IMAG0108.jpg');
echo $object->body;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the content-type header and output the readfile to the browser. What I do is create a new php file, like "showimage.php", that accepts an ID or some such to know what image to display. Then I use it in a browser page: .

In showimage.php, something like:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    readfile('/var/images/' . $_GET['id'] . '.png');
    // or
    // echo $object->body;
?>
```

That would read a file from the local system and output it as an image. Off the top of my head, so I might have messed up that code!

Comment: true - readfile will out to the buffer, no need to check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content: image/jpeg');
echo $object->body;
```

Should work fine (for JPEGs), you need know what filetype is in question and then send appropriate content headers.

Comment: it still displays the binary in the browser.

Comment: define `the binary`... if that's not image, you should see white page /image.

Comment: the source code...this is the first line `ÿØÿálÔExifMM*HTCbjr(‡izRPC36100HHˆ';0220‘’ , 0100  À   42011:04:19 21:21:382011:04:19 21:21:38ìdR980100 ¨(°kHHÿØÿÛ„     $.' `

Comment: You could paste entire code on http://pastebin.com or upload as text file... I see it is JPEG.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is it is hosted on Amazon. I can add metadata to the file (content type, content disposition, etc). I have tried adding content disposition inline in the metadata but that didn't change the outcome.

Comment: is the header an apache thing? It is hosted on Amazon and my php script is running locally.